# PHP class naming issue

Tags: php, class, oop, namespaces

I'm using CakePHP and when baking a table "cases", I get `syntax error, unexpected T_CASE, expecting T_STRING` from the model

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Case Model
 *
 */
class Case extends AppModel {
```

I'm guessing the error is because the class name is "Case", based off the db table.  Is this correct?  Are we not able to use "Case" as a class name?

Comment: Yep, 'case' is a reserved word.

Comment: [indeed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Comment: @jameslafferty - thanks, will defining a namespace make a difference?

Comment: @dcd018: Probably not.  You can't name it `Case` is the issue.  You need to use another name.

Comment: nope. A reserved keyword cannot be used outside its intended meaning.

Comment: Also, best practice is to have classes named as capitalized

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a reserved word conflict

Comment: @samira Your edit was wrong and I'm going to roll it back. Code spans and code blocks are commonly used for error messages and other output, in fact that's considered the preferred way to mark output. More generally...there seems to be an exceptionally easy panel of reviewers this evening who are rubber-stamping every suggested edit within seconds, but most of the edits you've been submitting are really not constructive. Please find things that actually need to be fixed and are significant enough to be worth editing rather than using suggested edits as a way to score rep with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Case` / `case` is a reserved word by PHP. You can try to use a prefix or just another name.